# Редирект после выполнения условия

Tags: редирект, php

Добрый день! Есть html форма. 
Нужно, что бы после нажатия на кнопку, которая отправляет форму, был редирект. т.е. редирект должен зависеть от того, какие данные введёт пользователь(если проверка выдаст **true**, то пользователя должно перекинуть на страницу, допустим, **auth.php**. Если же выдаст **false**, то пользователь должен остаться на странице ввода и получить окно с предупреждением).
**Интересует** как такое можно сделать на php, и возможно ли вообще такое сделать, так как если использовать header() то будем получать ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> если использовать header() то будем получать ошибку

Ну так исправьте эту ошибку и всего делов.
Скорее всего, к тому моменту как вы пытаетесь отправить новый заголовок через header, php уже отправил часть или всю страничку в браузер. А заголовки как известно после отправки странички передавать нельзя.
Самым простым решением будет в самом верху скрипта, сразу после <?php, вставить строчку ob_start(); И в самом низу, перед ?>, добавить echo ob_get_clean();

Comment: Случайно нашёл решение ещё проще!
<meta  http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php' >

Comment: Но Ваш вариант тоже подходит.

Comment: Тег meta блокируется некоторыми браузерами. Лучше на js: <script> document.location.href='index.php'; </script>

Comment: Да, думаю лучше конечно будет на жабке, но если она у кого отключена?